# Display laravel 8 inbuilt login page on url / or any other slug

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display laravel 8 login page on diffrent slug instead of "login", how i can changed it.

Comment: Change your `Route::` . Sow your Route code?

Comment: If you're using Fortify, https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/proper-way-to-override-jetstreamfortify-auth-routes?reply=658829

Comment: Show us some homework, this not how you ask a question. You should work on your code and put what you have done so far, here. Read the Help Center topics to learn more about what questions you can ask and what type of questions you have to avoid. [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Community will definitely be glad to help you for right questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your slug name as you want `/routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/set-your-slug-here', [AuthController::class, 'index']);
```

also, you can see this [Blog](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-custom-login-and-registration-exampleexample.html)

Comment: I want to change inbuilt login page url...it need create custome controllers??